# How can i get the data from the time between a process started and ended?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using DannyGeneral;


namespace CpuUsage
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<float> processValues;
        private bool alreadyRun;
        private DateTime dt;
        private DateTime dt1;
        private PerformanceCounter theCPUCounter;
        private PerformanceCounter theMemCounter;
        private PerformanceCounter specProcessCPUCounter;
        private float cpuUsage;
        private float memUsage;
        private List<float> Values;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            processValues = new List<float>();
            alreadyRun = false;
            dt = DateTime.Now;


            Values = new List<float>();
                theCPUCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
                theMemCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
                specProcessCPUCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);



        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            memUsage = theMemCounter.NextValue();
            label1.Text = memUsage.ToString();
            Logger.Write("Memory Usage   " + memUsage.ToString());
            cpuUsage = this.theCPUCounter.NextValue();
            label2.Text = cpuUsage.ToString();
            Logger.Write("Cpu Usage   " + this.cpuUsage.ToString());
            Values.Add(cpuUsage);
            isProcessRunning();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            dt1 = DateTime.Now;
            float Maximum = Values.Max();
            float Minimum = Values.Min();
            float Average = Values.Average();
            string t = string.Format("Maximum --- {0} , Minimum --- {1} , Average --- {2}", Maximum, Minimum, Average);
            Logger.Write(t);



            TimeSpan ts = (dt1 - dt);
            string time = ts.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
            Logger.Write("Time The Program Was Running ---   " + time);


        }

        private void isProcessRunning()
        {

                Process[] proclist = Process.GetProcessesByName("BFBC2Game");

                    if (proclist.Length > 0)
                    {
                        if (alreadyRun == false)
                        {
                            Logger.Write("Bfbc2 Started");
                            alreadyRun = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (alreadyRun == true)
                        {
                            Logger.Write("Bfbc2 Exited");
                            alreadyRun = false;
                        }
                    }

        }

    }
}
```

I just added a new List : processValues.
What i wanted to do is that when i exited the process for example in this case: BFBC2Game it will write for me to the logger the Max() Min() and Average() from the time the process started until it ended.

The problem is that the process might started after the program was running for few minutes and logged some info already. I want to get the max min and average only between the times the process started and ended.

So when i close the form the program exit the program in the logger text file i now see in the end:

```
8/31/2012--12:18 AM ==> Maximum --- 42.05113 , Minimum --- 0 , Average --- 13.19243
8/31/2012--12:18 AM ==> Time The Program Was Running ---   00:00:49
```

And inm the middle somewhere i see when the process started and exited:

```
8/31/2012--12:17 AM ==> Memory Usage   4435
8/31/2012--12:17 AM ==> Cpu Usage   5.57648
8/31/2012--12:17 AM ==> Bfbc2 Started
8/31/2012--12:17 AM ==> Memory Usage   4412
8/31/2012--12:17 AM ==> Cpu Usage   15.38422
8/31/2012--12:17 AM ==> Bfbc2 Exited
8/31/2012--12:18 AM ==> Memory Usage   4432
8/31/2012--12:18 AM ==> Cpu Usage   13.26883
```

Now i want that when i exit the application it will write me something like this in the end of the file:

```
8/31/2012--12:18 AM ==> Bfbc2 Started at 8/31/2012--12:17 AM
8/31/2012--12:19 AM ==> Maximum --- 42.05113 , Minimum --- 0 , Average --- 13.19243
8/31/2012--12:19 AM ==> Bfbc2 Exited at 8/31/2012--12:17 AM
```

So i will know to look in the end of the file when the process started an ended and what are the values mix min and average for the time the process was running.

Comment: If i've understood you correctly, you could log instances of a custom class instead of just the float. Then you can also log other informations like if the process was running and you are able to select only those values for the calculation of Min,Max and Average.

Comment: Sound like a good idea Tim i will think about how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch class. This is an sample code. This is [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-5.0) to corresponding Microsoft docs.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] array = new int[] { 4, 2, 5, 1, 3 };
        Stopwatch clock = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        SortRecursivly(array);
        clock.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Array sorted in {clock.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
    }
}
```